# Incorrect syntax near ' '

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This is the page behind code where it have error

```
if (Session["username"] != null)
   {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registerCS"].ConnectionString;

       string sql1 = "Select pemgrp from Profile where userID = '" + Session["username"].ToString() + "'";
      string sql = "Select studname from Profile where pemgrp = '" + sql1 + "'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        //open connection and execute command
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
        lb_classmates.Text = dr[0].ToString();

        }
    }
```

However, when i run, it give me this error :
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Is `userID` an `int`? If so, don't wrap it in apostrophes. But you should use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection and other issues anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter usersID is an String.

Comment: its a bad practice, use parameters for userId andpemgrp.. it will solve many issues..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are using sub-query therefore this

```
string sql = "Select studname from Profile where pemgrp = '" + sql1 + "'";
```

should be

```
string sql = "Select studname from Profile where pemgrp in (" + sql1+ ")";
```

and you should be using [Parametereized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2):

I think It should be

```
string sql = "Select studname from Profile where pemgrp in (" + sql1+ ")";
```

instead of

```
string sql = "Select studname from Profile where pemgrp = '" + sql1 + "'";
```

I would strongly recommend you to use **parametereized queries**

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameterized query something llike this

```
string sql = "Select studname from Profile where pemgrp = @p1";
```

and to pass parameter

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",sql1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[No One's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21137490/447156) is of course right.

If you want to use a subquery in a query, you should use [`IN (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

> Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a **subquery**
>   or a list.

```
test_expression [ NOT ] IN 
( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]
)
```

Also you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also consider to use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registerCS"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql1 = "Select pemgrp from Profile where userID = @username";
    string sql = "Select studname from Profile where pemgrp IN (" + sql1 + ")";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Session["username"].ToString());
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //
    }
}
```